# Random hex ID in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell and hard FP. I have been trying to come up with a function that would generate special type of ID for my project. The ID has 4 groups of 8 digits. The first two groups are always zeros and the other two groups are random 8 digit hex numbers. This is the code I came up with, but it seems to call a lot of things to achieve a simple result. What is the proper Haskell way of doing something like this?

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Numeric (showHex)

deviceId :: IO String
deviceId = sequence [zeros, zeros, bits, bits] >>= return . intercalate "-"
    where zeros = return "00000000"
          bits = randomRIO (0x10000000::Integer, 0xffffffff::Integer) >>= return . flip showHex ""
```

Edit: thanks to the comments my function now uses fmap and looks like this

```
deviceId :: IO String
deviceId = intercalate "-" <$> sequence [zeros, zeros, bits, bits]
    where zeros = return "00000000"
          bits = flip showHex "" <$> randomRIO (0x10000000::Integer, 0xffffffff::Integer)
```

The return on zeros makes sense to me, since it clearly indicates that we are operating on IO strings. Thanks. Any other improvements?

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with this. What part of it is off-putting to you?

Comment: It feels like I am going in and out of IO too much. I return on a string in zeros to type match the bits, but at the same time, I return on bits, so I can >>= on a showHex and then I return on the result, so I can do the final >>=. Feels like there has to be a more elegant way of going about it.

Comment: Following `>>=` with `return`  means you don't really need `Monad`. I would probably write `intercalate "-" <$> sequence [zeros, zeros, bits, bits]` and `flip showHex "" <$> randomRIO (0x10000000::Integer, 0xffffffff::Integer)` instead, where `<$>` is `fmap`.

Comment: First, you don't "go in and out of IO" in Haskell. Once you're in IO, you're there to stay. There is no way "out" of IO in the larger sense. You can bind values out of IO to be used in a pure way later, but the function where you do that will always be IO. Second, if you'd like to express the pure components without `return`s cluttering it up, you could express this with `do` notation instead? I also like @danidiaz's suggestion of using the `Functor` instance for IO here to essentially map your pure functions over the IO computations.

Comment: I understand that you cannot completely get rid of IO once you start with it. But it seems like major part of what monads are about is to allow applying pure functions to impure values. And once you are in a pure function you could be considered "out of IO", since you are no longer operating on monads.

Comment: @danidiaz thanks, that looks much more pleasant.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `return` in your `zeros` binding by doing something along the lines of
`intercalate "-" . ([zeros, zeros] ++ ) <$> sequence [bits, bits]`
or even `intercalate "-" . (zeros:) . (zeros:) <$> sequence [bits, bits]`. Wether this pleases your eye more is yours to determine. It does hide the fact that this in fact goes through the IO Monad, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the random-string package to handle both the random value and the rendering:

```
% git clone https://github.com/TomMD/random-string
Cloning into 'random-string'...
remote: Counting objects: 12, done.
remote: Total 12 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 12
Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done.
% cd random-string
% cabal new-repl
Resolving dependencies...
> import Data.List
> let zeros = pure $ replicate 8 '0'
> let rnd = randomString (StringOpts Base16 4)
> (intercalate "-") <$> sequence [zeros,zeros,rnd,rnd]
```

Which is to say the solution sans imports is extremely similar to what you already have:

```
f = intercalate "-" <$> sequence [z,z,r,r]
  where z = pure (replicate 8 '0')
        r = randomString (StringOpts Base16 4)
```

N.B. The range on my solution is different from yours.  I'm assuming you selected a random of 0x10000000-0xFFFFFFFF just because you wanted a full rendered 8 characters and didn't want to or know how to render the leading zeros.  If you want to pair down the range then the random-string package probably is more trouble than value.

Comment: You are right, the range is picked for convenience, so I don't have to do some sort of scanf-like operation on the resulting string.

Comment: Looks like random-sting is available through hackage https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-string

Comment: @MadWombat I guess so, I forgot about that.

Comment: I have tried a few times to implement the same thing through Text.Printf, but couldn't make printf play nicely with IO. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question should be opened for that. The `printf` function is polymorphic, but you should be able to use it as IO, such as `printf "%d\n" 42 :: IO ()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is tightly coupled with `IO`, which, depending on the design of your application, might not be very practical. Intuitively, the IO action is only necessary to produce a random seed, after that it is useless.

```
deviceId :: RandomGen g => g -> String
```

I've never played with random in Haskell, but I thought that "randomness" is a qualitative attribute of the input, not of the output (as depicted by the type of `deviceId` above). So I wondered whether there was a Random Comonad somewhere, and [it turns out there is](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-random-0.1.2/docs/Control-Comonad-Random.html).

```
-- Generates random hex strings of length n
randomHexString :: RandomGen g => Int -> g -> [String]
randomHexString n = (extracts next =<= take n . extracts next) . mkRandR ('0', 'f')
```

Now `deviceId` is as simple as

```
deviceId g = intercalate "-" xss where
  xss = zs ++ ws
  zs = replicate 2 (replicate 8 '0') 
  ws = take 2 $ randomHexString 8 g
```

and there's no IO in sight. Sadly, the comonad-random package is deprecated.

Still, you might want to generate a random seed at the end of the world and pass it around when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, need to read up on comonads. This sounds scary though, even if you only picked seed randomly, you would still be non-pure, since multiple runs would produce different streams of pseudo-randomness. Therefore you would still be in a monadic world somewhere.